# Comparar linea de archivo en c

Tags: c, string, archivo, fgets, fopen

¿Como puedo comparar una linea que levanto de un archivo con una palabra que quiero? quiero comparar una linea del archivo con "hola" si esta lo imprimo, tuve varios inconvenientes, es muy nuevo el lenguaje para mi y se me dificulta conseguir informacion para hacer cosas basicas (cosa que no pasa con otros lenguajes)

```
FILE * archivo = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
char line[100];
char palabra[10];
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),archivo)){

}
```

Comment: Usando `strcmp`.

Comment: Mira la documentacion de la funcion [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)...

Comment: o usando strstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es quitar el salto de línea que `fgets` deja en la cadena:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), archivo))
{
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
}
```

Lo siguiente es comparar la cadena, en C usamos la función `strcmp`:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), archivo))
{
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(line, "Hola") == 0)
    {
        puts("El texto coincide.");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("El texto no coincide.");
    }
}
```

También puedes comparar la cadena incluyendo el salto de línea:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), archivo))
{
    if (strcmp(line, "Hola\n") == 0)
    {
        puts("El texto coincide.");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("El texto no coincide.");
    }
}
```

Y ya que estás empezando, mejor hacerlo adquiriendo buenos hábitos. Siempre comprueba el resultado de `fopen`, podría ser que el archivo no existiera, que existiera pero no tuvieras permiso de lectura ... es un poco más de trabajo pero te ahorrará un montón de quebraderos de cabeza en el futuro:

```
FILE *archivo = fopen("texto.txt", "r");

if (archivo == NULL)
{
    perror("fopen");    // Esto devolverá información acerca del error
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // No tiene mucho sentido intentar leer un
                        // archivo que no se ha abierto
}
```

Comment: *También puedes comparar la cadena incluyendo el salto de línea..* No es buena idea, puesto que si la funcion fgets lee los `N` caracteres, entonces no incluye el salto de linea en el array y a pesar que las dos cadenas sean iguales (`Hola != Hola\n`), la condicion dara como resultado un `false`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 depende, es muy común querer confirmar que se ha incluido el salto de la linea en la cadena (eso indica que podemos evitar consumir caracteres para llegar al final de línea: `while (((c = getc(archivo)) != EOF) && (c != '\n'))`) y asegurarnos de que en la siguiente iteración empezamos en una línea nueva.

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender, la funcion [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) en este caso solo leera hasta `99` caracteres (de `0` a `98`), si el archivo, tiene una linea con 100 caracteres (incluyendo el salto de linea), entonces, `fgets` se queda con los primeros `99` caracteres y descarta el salto de linea. Entonces, al momento de comparar con la funcion `strcmp`, hay la posibilidad de que la condicion de un `false`, a pesar que las cadenas sean iguales, dara `false`.. La cuestion aqui, es que no se sabe cuando la funcion fgets va a incluir el salto de linea en `line`.

Comment: Por eso decia que no era una buena idea en este caso incluir el salto de linea en la segunda cadena literal de `strcmp`. Mas bien, para asegurar que la comprobacion de ambas cadenas sean iguales, se deberia verificar antes si en la ultima posicion tiene el salto de linea, si es `true`, se procede a reemplazar el caracter por el caracter nulo. Esto es algo que al final es poco probable que pase, pero igual se lo deberia de tomar en cuenta.

Comment: _La cuestion aqui, es que no se sabe cuando la funcion fgets va a incluir el salto de linea en line_ ¿A que te refieres con eso? `fgets` no inventa los saltos de línea, si los incluye es debido a que forman parte del stream (`archivo`) o bien a consecuéncia de la pulsación de un intro si se lee de `stdin`, hay varias formas de capturar el final de línea y no siempre procede reemplazarlo por el carácter `NUL`, como te decía, depende del contexto, no se puede elucubrar si procede o no en un snippet tan corto como el que muestra el OP.